# why (100 / "Apple") == Number.NaN is giving false?

Tags: javascript, nan

```js
let x =(100 / "Apple");
let y = Number.NaN;
console.log(`${x} ${y} ${x == y} ${typeof(x)} ${typeof(y)}`);
```

output: `"NaN NaN false number number"`

Why it is giving false when they have same value?

Comment: `NaN` does not equal anything, even `NaN`

Comment: `Number.isNaN` will help check for `NaN` values.